# apache server reboots continously

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

My Apache server dies every few seconds/minutes.
This kills my websites and doesn't allow them to operate.
I am running on CentOS on a VPS service.

There's a partial error_log (change IP and DNS names):

```
WARNING: MaxClients of 150 would require 6 servers,
 and would exceed the ServerLimit value of 2.
 Automatically lowering MaxClients to 50.  To increase,
 please see the ServerLimit directive.
[Fri May 31 12:50:54 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri May 31 12:50:54 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri May 31 12:50:54 2013] [notice] mod_bw : Memory Allocated 0 bytes (each conf takes 32 bytes)
[Fri May 31 12:50:54 2013] [notice] mod_bw : Version 0.8 - Initialized [0 Confs]
[Fri May 31 12:50:54 2013] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 2 max processes and 32 max threads.
[Fri May 31 12:50:55 2013] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Fri May 31 12:50:55 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:50:55 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:50:55 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:50:55 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:50:55 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:50:55 2013] [warn] Init: (MYSITE_DOMAIN1.com:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri May 31 12:50:55 2013] [warn] Init: (MYSITE_DOMAIN2.com:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri May 31 12:50:55 2013] [warn] Init: (MYSITE_DOMAIN3.com:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri May 31 12:50:55 2013] [warn] Init: (MYSITE_DOMAIN4.com:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri May 31 12:50:55 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: horde.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_horde.include:96) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:107)
[Fri May 31 12:50:55 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: horde.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_horde.include:49) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:54)
[Fri May 31 12:50:55 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: lists:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_server.include:204) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:54)
[Fri May 31 12:50:55 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: default-XXX_XXX_XXX_XXX:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_server.include:139) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:107)
[Fri May 31 12:50:55 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: default-YYY_YYY_YYY_YYY:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_server.include:105) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:54)
[Fri May 31 12:50:55 2013] [warn] Init: You should not use name-based virtual hosts in conjunction with SSL!!
[Fri May 31 12:50:55 2013] [notice] Apache configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 31 12:51:10 2013] [error] mod_fcgid: fcgid process manager died, restarting the server
[Fri May 31 12:51:11 2013] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: apr_thread_create: unable to create worker thread
[Fri May 31 12:51:14 2013] [warn] child process 17814 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri May 31 12:51:16 2013] [warn] child process 17814 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri May 31 12:51:18 2013] [warn] child process 17814 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri May 31 12:51:18 2013] [error] make_obcallback: could not import mod_python.apache.\n
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 22, in ?
[Fri May 31 12:51:20 2013] [error] child process 17814 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri May 31 12:51:21 2013] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
WARNING: MaxClients of 150 would require 6 servers,
 and would exceed the ServerLimit value of 2.
 Automatically lowering MaxClients to 50.  To increase,
 please see the ServerLimit directive.
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [notice] mod_bw : Memory Allocated 0 bytes (each conf takes 32 bytes)
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [notice] mod_bw : Version 0.8 - Initialized [0 Confs]
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 2 max processes and 32 max threads.
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [warn] Init: (MYSITE_DOMAIN1:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [warn] Init: (MYSITE_DOMAIN2.com:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [warn] Init: (MYSITE_DOMAIN3.com:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [warn] Init: (MYSITE_DOMAIN4.com:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: horde.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_horde.include:96) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:107)
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: horde.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_horde.include:49) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:54)
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: lists:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_server.include:204) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:54)
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: default-XXX_XXX_XXX_XXX:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_server.include:139) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:107)
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: default-YYY_YYY_YYY_YYY:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_server.include:105) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:54)
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [warn] Init: You should not use name-based virtual hosts in conjunction with SSL!!
[Fri May 31 12:51:23 2013] [notice] Apache configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 31 12:51:32 2013] [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: apr_thread_create: unable to create worker thread
[Fri May 31 12:51:38 2013] [error] mod_fcgid: fcgid process manager died, restarting the server
[Fri May 31 12:51:41 2013] [warn] child process 17839 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri May 31 12:51:44 2013] [warn] child process 17839 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri May 31 12:51:46 2013] [warn] child process 17839 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri May 31 12:51:48 2013] [error] child process 17839 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
WARNING: MaxClients of 150 would require 6 servers,
 and would exceed the ServerLimit value of 2.
 Automatically lowering MaxClients to 50.  To increase,
 please see the ServerLimit directive.
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [notice] mod_bw : Memory Allocated 0 bytes (each conf takes 32 bytes)
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [notice] mod_bw : Version 0.8 - Initialized [0 Confs]
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 2 max processes and 32 max threads.
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [warn] Init: (MYSITE_DOMAIN1:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [warn] Init: (MYSITE_DOMAIN2.com:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [warn] Init: (MYSITE_DOMAIN3.com:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [warn] Init: (MYSITE_DOMAIN4.com:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: horde.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_horde.include:96) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:107)
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: horde.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_horde.include:49) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:54)
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: lists:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_server.include:204) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:54)
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: default-XXX_XXX_XXX_XXX:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_server.include:139) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:107)
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: default-YYY_YYY_YYY_YYY:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_server.include:105) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:54)
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [warn] Init: You should not use name-based virtual hosts in conjunction with SSL!!
[Fri May 31 12:51:49 2013] [notice] Apache configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 31 12:52:29 2013] [error] mod_fcgid: fcgid process manager died, restarting the server
[Fri May 31 12:52:33 2013] [warn] child process 17852 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri May 31 12:52:33 2013] [warn] child process 17854 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri May 31 12:52:35 2013] [warn] child process 17852 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri May 31 12:52:35 2013] [warn] child process 17854 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri May 31 12:52:37 2013] [warn] child process 17852 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri May 31 12:52:37 2013] [warn] child process 17854 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Fri May 31 12:52:39 2013] [error] child process 17852 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri May 31 12:52:39 2013] [error] child process 17854 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Fri May 31 12:52:40 2013] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
WARNING: MaxClients of 150 would require 6 servers,
 and would exceed the ServerLimit value of 2.
 Automatically lowering MaxClients to 50.  To increase,
 please see the ServerLimit directive.
[Fri May 31 12:52:42 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri May 31 12:52:42 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri May 31 12:52:42 2013] [notice] mod_bw : Memory Allocated 0 bytes (each conf takes 32 bytes)
[Fri May 31 12:52:42 2013] [notice] mod_bw : Version 0.8 - Initialized [0 Confs]
[Fri May 31 12:52:42 2013] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 2 max processes and 32 max threads.
[Fri May 31 12:52:42 2013] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Fri May 31 12:52:44 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:52:44 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:52:44 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:52:44 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:52:44 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri May 31 12:52:44 2013] [warn] Init: (MYSITE_DOMAIN1:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri May 31 12:52:44 2013] [warn] Init: (MYSITE_DOMAIN2.com:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri May 31 12:52:44 2013] [warn] Init: (MYSITE_DOMAIN3.com:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri May 31 12:52:44 2013] [warn] Init: (MYSITE_DOMAIN4.com:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Fri May 31 12:52:44 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: horde.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_horde.include:96) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:107)
[Fri May 31 12:52:44 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: horde.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_horde.include:49) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:54)
[Fri May 31 12:52:44 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: lists:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_server.include:204) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:54)
[Fri May 31 12:52:44 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: default-XXX_XXX_XXX_XXX:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_server.include:139) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:107)
[Fri May 31 12:52:44 2013] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: default-YYY_YYY_YYY_YYY:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_server.include:105) vs. atmail.webmail:443 (/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/generated/13698586280.72967400_atmail.include:54)
[Fri May 31 12:52:44 2013] [warn] Init: You should not use name-based virtual hosts in conjunction with SSL!!
[Fri May 31 12:52:44 2013] [notice] Apache configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 31 12:52:50 2013] [error] mod_fcgid: fcgid process manager died, restarting the server
```

Can someone tell me what this problem can be?

Comment: Most people will associate reboot with a restart of the entire server. If you how ever mean that the apache process is /restarting/ that is something else. That wording is essential to the question and changes the scope of the question to much for anyone else to edit it even if we can infer it, without more information.

Answer (score 5):

Apache is telling you what the problem is.  You just need to listen.

> [Fri May 31 12:51:11 2013] **[alert]** (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: apr_thread_create: unable to create worker thread

Since this is a VPS I suspect you're hitting a limit imposed by your provider (probably RAM, possibly number of processes/threads).
Contact your provider for assistance in determining what limit you're hitting and possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You should correct your http configuration files according to the information provided in the error log.  I'd use http://httpd.apache.org as a reference too.